# How to hide a column in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to 'hide' the percentage column in the following query?

```
SELECT 
    ((SUM(is_correct) / COUNT(*)) * 100) percentage, worker_id 
FROM 
    main_mturklog 
GROUP BY 
    worker_id HAVING percentage < 80
```

Basically, I only want to view the `worker_id` in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    worker_id 
FROM 
    main_mturklog 
GROUP BY 
    worker_id 
HAVING ((SUM(is_correct) / COUNT(*)) * 100) < 80
```